# jq: error : Cannot iterate over null (null)

Tags: json, jq, git-bash

In the below Json file, I am trying to extract "Name": "abcd","Version": "1.0.2" and "Severity": "Medium".

```
"status": "scanned",
    "data": {
        "Layer": {
            "IndexedByVersion": 3,
            "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
            "ParentName": "e762",
            "Name": ".4530bfac-5e99-4138-b071-4286c06669a3",
            "Features": [
                {
                    "Name": "openssl1.0",
                    "VersionFormat": "dpkg",
                    "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
                    "AddedBy": "85aa73fb8281cc252ed7e151f10386f36588ec6c967d45136103a4e1e705a81c.01bc7eff-9a5d-43f5-ab14-2e3e470cba77",
                    "Version": "1.0.2q-1~deb9u1",
                    "Vulnerabilities": [
                        {
                            "Severity": "Medium",
                            "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
                            "Link": "xxxx",
                            "FixedBy": "1.0.2r-1~deb9u1",
                            "Description": " n must call SSL_shutdown() twice even if a protocol error has occurred (applications should not do this but some do anyway). Fixed in OpenSSL 1.0.2r (Affected 1.0.2-1.0.2q).",
                            "Name": "CVE-2019-1559",
                            "Metadata": {
                                "NVD": {
                                    "CVSSv2": {
                                        "Score": 4.3,
                                        "Vectors": "AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:P/I:N"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "VersionFormat": "dpkg",
                    "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
                    "Version": "0.16-1+deb9u1",
                    "Name": "libidn2-0",
                    "AddedBy": "85aa73fb8281cc252ed7e151f10386f36588ec6c967d45136103a4e1e705a81c.01bc7eff-9a5d-43f5-ab14-2e3e470cba77"
                },
                {
                    "VersionFormat": "dpkg",
                    "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
                    "Version": "0.29-4",
                    "Name": "pkg-config",
                    "AddedBy": "4d2169f1dc7652ffd2a4f32d2c0ae2
                },


                {
                    "Name": "nettle",
                    "VersionFormat": "dpkg",
                    "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
                    "AddedBy": "7494d6c991278b43e8388f7cec2f138075
                    "Version": "3.3-1",
                    "Vulnerabilities": [
                        {
                            "Severity": "Low",
                            "NamespaceName": "debian:9",
                            "Link": "xxxx",
                            "Description": "er.",
                            "Name": "CVE-2018-16869",
                            "Metadata": {
                                "NVD": {
                                    "CVSSv2": {
                                        "Score": 3.3,
                                        "Vectors": ":P"
                                    }
```

So far I am able to extract the values of Name & version using the jq command below.

```
jq -r '.data.Layer| .Features[] | "\(.Name) \(.Version)"' status.json
```

but when I try to extract values of "Severity" field using the below command

```
`jq -r '.data.Layer| .Features[] | "\(.Name) \(.Version)"| .Vulnerabilities[].Severity' status.json`
```

I get the error message in the title.

```
Required output: abcd 12.0 medium
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you extend the sample document in the question to be a [mcve]? Right now the sample subset of the input document isn't syntax-compliant (opens structures it doesn't close), isn't minimal (includes contents that are irrelevant to the output), and doesn't exercise failure cases (you want to ignore items with no Vulnerabilities, but don't show any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes the output format slightly:

```
jq -r '.data.Layer| .Features[] | .Name ,.Version, .Vulnerabilities[].Severity' input
```

But this also works:

```
jq -r '.data.Layer| .Features[] | "\(.Name)  \(.Version)  \(.Vulnerabilities[].Severity)"' input
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I ran into another issue with extracting the fields. I just edited the source JSON file. I need to get the field/key (Name,Version,Severity) values where "Vulnerabilities" field is not NULL/empty.

Answer (score 1):

if an alternative solution is acceptable, let me offer you a solution based on a walk-path unix tool for JSON: **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)** (accommodating your comment to William):

This way, you'll collect `Name`, `Version` and `Severity` only predicated `Severity` record is present in `Vulnerabilities` (and, obviously, if `Vulnerabilities` record exists):

```
bash $ <status.json jtc -x'<Features>l[:][Vulnerabilities]<Severity>l[^4]' -y'[Name]' -y'[Version]' -y'<Severity>l' 
"openssl1.0"
"1.0.2q-1~deb9u1"
"Medium"
"nettle"
"3.3-1"
"Low"
bash $
```

And, if you like to group those on each line, pipe it to `xargs`, or `paste`:

```
bash $ <status.json jtc -x'<Features>l[:][Vulnerabilities]<Severity>l[^4]' -y'[Name]' -y'[Version]' -y'<Severity>l' | xargs -L3
openssl1.0 1.0.2q-1~deb9u1 Medium
nettle 3.3-1 Low
bash $
```

Disclosure: I'm the creator of `jtc` tool

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Vulnerabilities[]?` instead of `[]` jq will just skip the Features which don't have a Vulnerability.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pitching in on StackOverflow! Your answer seems a bit unclear and might leave readers scratching their heads. Could you provide more context or clarify your points to make it easier to follow? Feel free to [edit] your answer for better clarity and understanding.